Boot process hangs on systemd-rfkill.service
I'm a beginner. I have successfully installed my first Raspberry Pi 5. It worked fine until, after a reboot (not the first one), the boot process hangs at this step:
systemd-rfkill.service

I tried to reinstall the SD card and again, after an apt upgrade and "reboot", the system hangs.
I don't even know how to investigate the problem. Any suggestions?
update
I finally understood that the problem was due to the external USB drive I added to /etc/fstab. Adding "nofail" to the mount options solves the boot problem.
Now the problem is why the USB drive fails to mount... maybe a problem with the charger.

If you end up having to reinstall again1, before you run the update:
sudo systemctl mask systemd-rfkill

This will render the service unrunnable, since normally it is triggered by something else (it's a "static" service).  Grepping through /lib/systemd, though, this "something else" is that rfkill is configured to run if the other thing does -- ie., it isn't a dependency for anything, so this should not cause a problem in that sense.
However, it may leave your wifi broken next boot. If so, check rfkill list; phy0 will probably be blocked and you'll have to sudo rfkill unblock phy0 manually and restart networking.


If you can't get boot to finish but you don't want to reinstall again and you can put the card in a computer where you can access the second partition (so, not Windows or MacOS...), create a symlink in /etc/systemd/system:
 ln -s systemd-rfkill.service /dev/null

Which is exactly what systemctl mask ... does.



Now it fails with: failed to listen on systemd-rfkill.socket

:/ That's the "something else" I was referring to...  You could try unmask on that.  If it still  doesn't work, leave another comment here to remind me and I will poke around more tomorrow (about to leave for the day now).

Please look at the update in my question... seems that the problem has nothing to do with rfkill
